# CATiledLayer renders too little tiles on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, macos-big-sur

`CATiledLayer` doesn't work as expected for me on macOS.
It's choosing to render too little tiles for a specific scale.

In my example, my view is `300px` wide and the scale is `4x`.
In that case, `CATiledLayer` renders only two tiles: `50px wide at 2x scale`, and stretches them.

Interestingly, when I run similar code on iOS, it works correctly - it renders 3 tiles, `25px wide at 4x scale`.

Is is a bug on macOS or am I missing something here?

My code below:

[image]

```swift
class WaveformView: NSView {

    var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer?.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, scale, 1.0, 1.0)
            layer?.setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
        }
    }

    private var tiledLayer: CATiledLayer { layer as! CATiledLayer }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        wantsLayer = true

        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 8
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 8
        tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: .infinity)
        tiledLayer.contentsScale = 1.0
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        let nsContext = NSGraphicsContext.current!
        let cgContext = nsContext.cgContext
        cgContext.saveGState()

        let scaleX: CGFloat = cgContext.ctm.a

        NSColor.red.setStroke()
        NSBezierPath(rect: dirtyRect)
            .stroke()

        let fontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
        let attr = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
          ]
        let str = "S: \(scaleX)\n\(dirtyRect.width)" as NSString
        str.draw(at: NSPoint(x: dirtyRect.minX, y: dirtyRect.midY), withAttributes: attr)

        nsContext.cgContext.restoreGState()
    }

    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        return CATiledLayer()
    }

}
```

Comment: 8 levels of detail and a tile size with an infinite height?

Comment: Infinite height because I'm only scaling the view horizontally and so I don't need multiple vertical tiles. As for the level of details - I tried setting much larger values but the result is the same.

Comment: I would suggest much _smaller_ values. This stuff goes wild; it's exponential don't you know...

Comment: Actually, it seems that things break apart when I set `transform scale` on only X axis. Setting it on both X and Y axis kinda fixed the problem...Although it's not exactly what I want, as I'm only interested in scaling in one direction, uh...:<